# OMNet++-How to set up the connection between RSU node and Vehicle nodes

Tags: omnet++, veins

I've read through the tictoc example code,and currently trying to manipulate the connection between RSU node and vehicle node using the example code in Veins,which is RSUExampleScenario.
After checking the only NED file of this example,there's only submodules for RSU nodes,which look like this

```
submodules:
    rsu[2]: RSU {
        @display("p=162,140;i=veins/sign/yellowdiamond;is=vs");
    }
```

And I'm really confused right now cause according to what I've learned from tictoc tutorial,I should manipulate the module connection from NED file.In tictoc tutorial it looks like this

```
submodules:
    tic: Txc1;
    toc: Txc1;
connections:
    tic.out --> {  delay = exponential(200ms); } --> toc.in;
    tic.in <-- {  delay = 100ms; } <-- toc.out;
```

So I'm now hoping to have some suggestion to clarify my question,where's the submodule for vehicle nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a closer look to the `RSUExampleScenario` you'll see that this network inherits the `Scenario` network. Here you'll find the `connections allowunconnected` statement.

On a very abstract level we can explain this as follows:

Unlike the TicToc Tutorial, the Scenario in Veins is wireless, so there is nothing like "the connection between RSU and vehicle". The technical realization is probably not important for current issue. Based on your configuration there is no need to adapt the network in terms of connections.

> ... where's the submodule for vehicle nodes?

This is the `Car` module that is located in `veins/src/veins/nodes/Car.ned`